# Can I allow a user to add additional tabs in quicktabs?

Tags: blocks, entities

In the same way that we can set a field to unlimited, allowing a user to add more than one value, might there be a way to do the same using quicktabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not so much about quicktabs, but I did find a work around. I ended up using plain old field groups. This module has logic in it where if containing fields have no content, don't display that tab (or "horizontal item" in this case).